# Bijective function between two nested lists (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, function

I want to define a function in Python to establish a bijection between two nested lists. The two lists are `a` and `b` and I want to map `a[i][j]` to `b[i][j]`.

I am unable to do this, however. I tried using a `while` loop as well as a `for` loop to iterate over the indices of the elements of the lists but to no avail.

I am new to Python so any help with this would be appreciated.

Here is the code I attempted. I have the following two lists, `lastcoldata` and `firstcoldata` (provided below) and I want to make the above-mentioned bijection between them.

```
lastcoldata=[[4], [0, 5, 6], [3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [1, 2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

firstcoldata=[[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [5, 6], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

def bijection(num):
    i=0;j=0
    while i<27:
        while j<len(lastcoldata[i]):
            if num==lastcoldata[i][j]:
                return firstcoldata[i][j]
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
```

For example, I tried calling `bijection(lastcoldata[1][0])` and there was no output, while the expected output was `1`. It worked fine for `bijection(lastcoldata[1][1])` and `bijection(lastcoldata[1][2])` respectively, giving outputs `2` and `3` respectively.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Please edit your post to add example calls, the expected results and the what you get instead (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only mistake is that you do not reset the value of `j`. It keeps on incrementing and after a point, it will never enter the second loop

For Loop Solution

```
def bijection(num) :
    for i in range(len(lastcoldata)) :
        for j in range(len(lastcoldata[i])) :
            if num == lastcoldata[i][j] :
                return firstcoldata[i][j]
    return None
```

While Loop Solution

```
def bijection(num):
    i=0;
    while i < 27:
        j=0;
        while j < len(lastcoldata[i]):
            if num == lastcoldata[i][j]:
                return firstcoldata[i][j]
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for the `while` loop! In the `for` loop solution what does the `return None` do? I tried exactly the same with the `for` loop but without the `return None` and it did not work.

Comment: `return None` is not really doing anything. You can even remove it. Should work.
This is more like to specify that the item you are looking for, was not found. It's just good practise to have a default `return something`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which avoids indexes and is more pythonic:

```
def bijection(num):
    for li, fi in zip(lastcoldata, firstcoldata):
        for lj, fj in zip(li, fi):
            if lj == num:
                return fj
    return None
```

If the parameter is not found it returns None.

By the way, it is also quicker:

```
%timeit bijection(2)
3.32 µs ± 37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

versus

```
4.11 µs ± 27.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

of the first solution given above by @Marmik

Comment: Great! I totally forgot about the zip operator.